# Making the phone silent on nearing a particular location

Tags: android

I am making an android application to show the position of a user on a map, along with the users current longitude and latitude, I have also used reverse geocoding to show the address of the android device. Now I plan to add a feature that if the user is near a particular place the phone automatically switches to silent mode, for this I have made a function to check whether the phone is already silent or not. Now I want to make another one, which puts the phone in silent mode on nearing a particular location.

The method which I have made to make the phone go silent on nearing a particular location is

```
public void changeToSilent(Location location){

    if(distanceTo(xxxx)<100)
    {
        if(mPhoneIsSilent==true){
        }
        else
        {
            mPhoneIsSilent = true;
            mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am calling this method in another function, which is....

public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
 { 
        Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged with location " + location.toString());   Stringtext=String.format("Lat:\t%f\nLong:\t%f\nAlt:\t%f\nBearing:\t%f",location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(), location.getAltitude(), location.getBearing());
this.locationText.setText(text);

```
    changeToSilent(location);

    try {
      List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 10); 
      for (Address address : addresses) {
        this.locationText.append("\n" + address.getAddressLine(0));
      }

      int latitude = (int)(location.getLatitude() * 1000000);
      int longitude = (int)(location.getLongitude() * 1000000);

      GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitude,longitude);
      mapController.animateTo(point); 

    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("LocateMe", "Could not get Geocoder data", e);

    }
  }
```

Now I am calling the above function in the oncreate method. Now suppose I know the latitude and longitude of the place near which the phone should go to silent.
What I want to know is, what do I have to write in place of xxxx in the changetosilent method?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. What is your question? And, in anticipation that your question is "how do I do this?", what have you tried?

Comment: post your code as an edit to your question please instead of the comments.

Comment: I have made the following method to change the mode of the phone to silent.

public void changeToSilent(Location location){
  
  if(distanceTo(xxxx)<100)
  {
   if(mPhoneIsSilent==true){
   }
   else
   {
    mPhoneIsSilent = true;
    mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
   }
  }
 }

Comment: Now suppose I have the place near which I want to make the phone go silent, then what should I use in place of 'xxxxx' in my changetoSilent method?

Comment: Ok, Tim. Sorry didn't see your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) to change the system volume levels.

here is an example:

```
AudioManager am =  (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE); 
//am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,6,0); //<-- use this one to set the volume
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT); //<-- to put on mute.
```

**EDIT:** Get a [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) object and use [loc.distanceBetween()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29);

Comment: The problem I am facing is with my distanceTo() method. I have edited my question, can you please read it again and if possible give a solution to my problem. Thank you.